# How can I ignore a Raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the example for this, I use two `Raycasts` that shoot forward, `ray1` is positioned at the top of my player and `ray2` is positioned at the bottom. Both Raycasts must detect an object in front of them in order for my character to be able to climb that object using the W and F keys simultaneously.

However my issue is, once the requirement to climb has been completed (`ray1` & `ray2` both detect) and I am now climbing, is there any way to then "disable" `ray1`? Since once climbing has begun, I don't need that `Raycast` anymore, all I need is `ray2` which is positioned at the bottom of my player. Using `!ray1` does not work as that prevents climbing all together. So basically I just need `ray2` until climbing starts, and then it's no longer used until I stop climbing and then try to climb an object again.

```
// Update()
bool ray1 = Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up * -0.8f, transform.forward, 0.6f);
bool ray2 = Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up * 1f, transform.forward, 0.6f);
if (ray1 && ray2)
{
    isAbleToClimbWall = true;
}
else
{      
    isAbleToClimbWall = false;
}

if (isAbleToClimbWall)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
    {
        if (ray1)
        {
            gravity = 0f;
            velocity.y = -2f;
            controller.Move(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }              
    }   
    else
    { 
        isAbleToClimbWall = false;
    }    
}
```

In the code snippet, at the very top the relevant `bool` turns **true** when both `Raycasts` detect an object. From there inside the `bool` if statement, after I begin climbing by pressing the two keys I insert just `ray1` and I leave out `ray2` but this prevents my character from being able to climb at all.

Comment: if (!sClimbing) ray1= ....

Comment: `bool ray1 = isAbleToClimb || Raycast(...)`  Breaks down to: "If able to climb, dont do raycast, otherwise do the raycast"

Comment: @hijinxbassist Thanks for the reply. My issue is that I want both Raycasts to work at the start (which they do), but once `isAbleToClimb = true`, then I would like to stop the second Raycast (`ray2`) from functioning during climbing. I tried `!ray2` but it isn't enough. The best way I can put it is, essentially while I am climbing, it should be like `ray2` does not exist at all.

Comment: Your post said you wanted to stop ray1.  regardless, just use that same condition on ray2 instead.  `bool ray2 = isAbleToClimb || Raycast(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment up front: In your description you say that `ray1` is at the top and `ray2` is at the bottom of your player, but from your code I would assume the opposite!

- `ray1` is at a position lower than the player `transform.position + transform.up * -0.8f`
- `ray2` is at a higher position `transform.position + transform.up * 1f`

Also you assignment to the velocity seems  bit weird as I would expect a **positive** value for climbing **up** but you do

```
velocity.y = -2f;
```

Also you never even use the `velocity` but then do

```
controller.Move(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

---

Anyway, in general just think in **states**. I would probably

- simply introduce an additional flag `isClimbing`
- move the raycasts to methods / properties. This way

  - you an reuse them without having to maintain multiple places
  - they are only evaluated if needed

So something like e.g.

```
private bool isClimbing;

// see comment above might need to adjust those according to you needs
// these are properties and always evaluated when accessed
private bool bottomHit => Physics.Raycast(transform.position - transform.up * 0.8f, transform.forward, 0.6f);
private bool topHit => Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up * 1f, transform.forward, 0.6f);

private void Update()
{
    if(!isClimbing) // we are currently not climbing
    {
        // if topHit fails then bottomHit isn't even evaluated at all
        if(topHit && bottomHit) // we can start climbing
        {
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                gravity = 0f;
                isClimbing = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else // we are currently climbing
    {
        // Check if we need to stop climbing
        // either if we have reached the top -> bottomHit stopped hitting
        // or if the F is no longer held down
        // again assuming checking Input is faster -> if the key is not pressed then the bottomHit isn't even evaluated
        if(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F) || !bottomHit)
        {
            gravity = YOUR_NORMAL_GRAVITY;
            isClimbing = false;
        }
        else // we are climbing and want to continue climbing
        {
            // again I simply assumed that a movement upwards should be positive
            // might need to flip the values
            // and/or even remove the S key part - also just based on the assumption you also want to climb down
            velocity.y = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) ? speed : Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) ? -speed : 0f;

            // instead of handling this here separate from any other movement logic
            // you should actually rather only assign the velocity.y accordingly
            // and then have a single central controller.Move call
            
        }
    }


    // probably some other input and movement logic here ...

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I went through this for a while and the comments are extremely useful. I did end up fixing the issue on my own while in class. I actually used `velocity = -2f;` and it was because if I jumped a millisecond before climbing began, my player would fly in the sky and that seemed to solve it. Sorry also for the typo in my post regarding `ray1` and `ray2` and thanks again for taking the time to provide a really detailed answer. I will refer to this in the future for sure.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want. As I understand - you need to keep `isAbleToClimbWall` set to true until it finishes climbing. So maybe keep it true, until ray2 detects object? Or introduce ray3 which would do that. There are many ways I guess...

Comment: Right now how it works is if `ray1` and `ray2` both detect an object, `isAbleToClimbWall` turns true and I can climb. But when I am climbing, I want to disable `ray2` while still keeping `ray1` working, if that makes sense.

Comment: if( !isAbleToClimbWall)  ray2 = Physics...     else   ray=true or false, maybe that solves your problem....

Comment: I would add that code inside the `isAbleToClimbWall` bool after my W and F input right?